# Eclipse does not recognize Jsoup JAR file in Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jar, jsoup

I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse 3.6.1(Helios). I have added JAR files to the build path for this project and they all worked perfectly fine. However, `Jsoup` is one JAR file that is not being recognized. Whenever I attempt to run my Servlet it my Dynamic Web Project, I get the error in the server logs stating `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup`. Upon further inspection in the Class File Editor, I see the message

`The JAR file /Users/ongozahcomputer/Downloads/jsoup-1.8.2.jar has no source attachment. You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:` "

I have configured the build path of the package in which all my files are contained, hit `add external JARs` and added `jsoup-1.8.2.jar`. It is appearing in the build path. I also, upon other user's suggestions, added `jsoup-1.8.2.jar` to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of my project. I am really stumped as to why it isn't being recognized and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is the console output:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[server.HelloServlet2]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet server.HelloServlet2 threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup
    at server.HelloServlet2.doGet(HelloServlet2.java:149)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:637)
```

Comment: Right click on project > properties >Java Build Path >Order and Export [Tab] > check whether jsoup jar is ticked.If not tick it > Clean > Build > Run.

Comment: [Eclipse - add .jar to Dynamic Web Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11652431/eclipse-add-jar-to-dynamic-web-project) -> especially [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15173716/1393766).

Comment: Also [Adding 3rd party jars to WEB-INF/lib automatically using Eclipse/Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5467530/1393766)

Answer (score 1):

You have added the jar files for compiling your dynamic web project. The same should be done while executing your application. 
`Right click on your dynamic web project and click run As and Run configurations. Click the classpath and check the jar file is added there or not.` If not, Add it to the classpath this will referred while executing the dynamic web application.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jars to
1. WEB-INF/lib folder.
2. Tomcat/lib folder.

Clean the server,
Restart it,
and Run the application.

This worked for me.